How do I configure Java Util Logging to show logging as log4j?
I've tried several options (I really tried) but I cannot get a formatting similar to Log4j. In short, I would like to output log lines with the following format:
2014-09-24 14:05:18 INFO  CustomerController:96 - Starting purchase order...
------------------- ----- ---------------------   --------------------------
Timestamp           Level Class & line            Message

In log4j I used to set the pattern:
d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}(%L) - %m%n

That is:

A single log line.
A local timestamp (no time zone)
A 5-letter level. "INFO" is padded with a single space.
Class name (no package) and line number.
Message.

I'm OK to use an internal config file in the deployable JAR, or using internal Java programmatic configuration. As long as I don't need to deploy an external "extra" file that would work for our environment.

What I do is write a class that extends java.util.logging.Formatter and then indicate that in the logging configuration properties file, i.e. java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=MyFormatter where MyFormatter is the name of my class that extends java.util.logging.Formatter. Is that an acceptable solution?

Log messages are formatted by a java.util.logging.Formatter. Unfortunately, neither of the built-in implementations seem to provide what you want. The closest you can get is a SimpleFormatter with a format of %1$TF %1$TT %4$-5s - %5$s%6$s (the %6$s is for exceptions). That will give you everything you want except the class name and line number. You can modify the format to include the source, but there doesn't seem to be a way to omit the package (or method name). And there's no way to define a format that includes the line number.
I think your only option is to create your own Formatter implementation (or find an existing third-party implementation). The following seems to meet your requirements:
package com.example;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.StackWalker.StackFrame;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CustomFormatter extends Formatter {

  // formatter used to format the log's timestamp
  private static final DateTimeFormatter DTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

  @Override
  public String format(LogRecord record) {
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    appendDateTime(record, builder);
    appendLevel(record, builder);
    appendClassNameAndLineNumber(record, builder);
    appendMessage(record, builder);
    appendThrown(record, builder);
    return builder.toString();
  }

  private void appendDateTime(LogRecord record, StringBuilder builder) {
    var zdt = record.getInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    builder.append(DTF.format(zdt));
  }

  private void appendLevel(LogRecord record, StringBuilder builder) {
    var name = record.getLevel().getName();
    builder.append(" ");

    // You seem to want the name to be padded *or* truncated in order to
    // fit within 5 spaces. Note this logic won't necessarily work if you
    // change the call from 'getName()' to 'getLocalizedName()'. Also, if
    // a custom level's name contains surrogate pairs, then they could
    // possibly be "cut in half".
    switch (name) {
      case "FINEST"  -> builder.append("FINST");
      case "FINER"   -> builder.append("FINER");
      case "FINE"    -> builder.append("FINE ");
      case "CONFIG"  -> builder.append("CNFIG");
      case "INFO"    -> builder.append("INFO ");
      case "WARNING" -> builder.append("WARN ");
      case "SEVERE"  -> builder.append("SEVRE");
      default -> {
        int len = name.length();
        if (len == 5) {
          builder.append(name);
        } else if (len < 5) {
          // StringBuilder::repeat added in Java 21
          builder.append(name).repeat(" ", 5 - len);
        } else {
          builder.append(name, 0, 5);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void appendClassNameAndLineNumber(LogRecord record, StringBuilder builder) {
    var frame = new SourceFinder().get();
    if (frame != null) {
      var className = frame.getClassName();
      int index = className.lastIndexOf('.');
      if (index != -1) {
        className = className.substring(index + 1);
      }
      builder.append(" ").append(className).append(":").append(frame.getLineNumber());
    }
  }

  private void appendMessage(LogRecord record, StringBuilder builder) {
    builder.append(" - ").append(formatMessage(record)).append(System.lineSeparator());
  }

  private void appendThrown(LogRecord record, StringBuilder builder) {
    var thrown = record.getThrown();
    if (thrown != null) {
      var sw = new StringWriter();
      thrown.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw, true));
      builder.append(sw.toString());
    }
  }

  // Inspired by the private java.util.logging.LogRecord$CallerFinder class
  private static class SourceFinder implements Predicate<StackFrame>, Supplier<StackFrame> {

    private static final StackWalker WALKER = StackWalker.getInstance();

    private boolean foundLogger;

    @Override
    public StackFrame get() {
      foundLogger = false;
      return WALKER.walk(s -> s.filter(this).findFirst()).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(StackFrame t) {
      if (!foundLogger) {
        foundLogger = t.getClassName().equals(Logger.class.getName());
        return false;
      }
      return !t.getClassName().startsWith("java.util.logging");
    }
  }
}

You may want to increase the "padding" used by the level name. Of just the predefined levels, there's WARNING which has a length of 7. And that's ignoring whether or not you want to modify the above to get the level's localized name instead.
Here's an example using the above formatter:
package com.example;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

  static {
    var root = Logger.getLogger("");
    for (var handler : root.getHandlers()) {
      handler.setFormatter(new CustomFormatter());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    var logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    logger.info("This is a test message..."); // line 16
  }
}

Output:
2024-09-24 09:42:45 INFO  Main:16 - This is a test message...


Excellent solution. Couple of minor issues: 1) Missing newline after the log line (easy to add), 2) Added extra logic to render all levels as 5-char strings. It works like a charm. Thank you!

Thanks for pointing out any issues. I've edited the code of CustomFormatter. As you said, fixing the first issue was easy (though note as a consequence of adding a new line after the message, I've modified appendThrown to not prepend a new line before the stack trace). I also modified appendLevel so that the name always has a length of 5 (though the example is not Unicode friendly). Not sure if it's similar to your implementation, but perhaps it'll be helpful to you or someone that reads this answer in the future.
